# Django Admin Commands

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm working with the latest version of Django and Python. I'm porting an application I had originally written in PHP to Python so I'm still a bit new to the Python world.

What I'm after is documented here -> [custom-management-commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/)

I've got those examples working just fine. However here is my dilemma...

I have for example two apps called "apache" and "nginx". In each of these I need to have a command called `config_add` which of course creates the respective configuration. The apps are separated this way to show all functions under that app belong to that specific type of work that needs to be done.

I run my command like so -> python manage.py config_add [args_here]

So of course, with two apps using the same command name as `config_add` only one will work, which I assume is based on the loading order of the installed apps.

What I'd like to do instead and this is the part I haven't figured out yet is this:

- python manage.py apache config_add [args_here]
- python manage.py nginx config_add [args_here]

These are only two examples, I also have apps like "mail", "postgres", etc.. which all also use the config_add name in them.

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: you can give new argument and depending on that, run the appropriate logic under one command